# How can I use flexbox to manage two items on a page where one is of indeterminate length

Tags: css, flexbox

I am building a single page web app that needs to run on both mobile phones and the desktop.  Its based on custom elements - although that is not necessarily important for the substance of the question.
I am attempting to achieve a layout like the following two (ascii) pictures

Mobile Phone Layout...

```
 ----------------
  Page Header
 ----------------
  Content

 ...
 ----------------
   spare space
 
  Action Buttons
 ----------------
  App Tool Bar
 ----------------
```

Desktop Layout...

```
 ----------------
   App Tool Bar
 ----------------
  Page Header
 ----------------
  Content

 ...
 ----------------
  Action Buttons
 
  spare space
 ----------------
```

The principal I am working on is that on a mobile phone I want the App Tool Bar and the Action Buttons as close to the thumbs as possible, on a desktop I want the layout more normal.

I can deal with the App Tool Bar easily enough, using flex box direction to `column reverse`, and a media query based on width of the device to change to flex box direction to `column`

I deal with Page Header `<header>` and the rest `<section>` with flex box direction `column`

So I am left with the content and action buttons. sections.  Because I am using a custom element to layout this part and `<slot>` elements to import that actual content, I don't know how big they are going to be.  They are effectively organised as

```
<div class="container">
  <section class="scrollable">
    <slot class="content"></slot>
  </section>
  <div class="action">
    <slot name="action"></slot>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is that the `<section class="scrollable">` exactly wraps its content with the space below it containing the `<div class="action">` and that as the content grows the `<div>` shrinks until its its natural size, at which point the `<section>` gains a scrollbar.  I can then handle the `<div>` with a normal css of `align-item: flex-end;` and a media query of `align-item: flex-start;` to position

Trying all the combinations I can think of, I either end up with the action buttons squeezed to the bottom regardless, the content and buttons sharing the page 50/50 or the action buttons taking the entire space and the scrollable area shrunk to zero pixels high.